# Alternate to Handle.exe(sysinternals)

Tags: windows

We are using Handle.exe by sysinternals, to detect file handles from command-line utility, but we are unable to package the Handle.exe into our product due to license issue. Even we tried fuser.exe to detect file handles from command-line utility, but fuser.exe is not working on windows-2003-64 server, windows-2008-32 and windows-2012 server.

Is there any alternative command-line utility to detect file handles.

Comment: Can always code your own or pay someone to do it for you...

Comment: Pretty sure there are already questions about how to do this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is an article [Examine Information on Windows NT System Level Primitives](https://www.codeguru.com/windows/examine-information-on-windows-nt-system-level-primitives/) which shows the source code for a `WhoUses.exe` tool which does what you need.